# How can I write a loop condition that only accepts input from A-D, and F, and a-d, and f

Tags: c

I have a program that is supposed to accept 4 inputs in main() and then shift and convert to uppercase using functions. I have everything done except that I need the program to be able to only accept A-D, F and a-d, f inputs. Using while loop and ASCII values for the characters, so far I have this:

```
char c1, c2, c3, c4;
 printf ("Enter 4 letter grades to find statistics: ");
 scanf("%c %c %c %c", &c1, &c2, &c3, &c4);
 getchar();
 while ((c1 < 'A' || c1 > 'D' && c1 != 'F') && (c1 < 'a' || c1 > 'd' && c1 != 'f')) {
       printf ("\n ERROR: Choose ONLY A-D, or F! \n Enter 4 letter grades to find statistics: ");
       scanf("%c %c %c %c", &c1, &c2, &c3, &c4); }
 while ((c2 < 'A' || c2 > 'D' && c2 != 'F') && (c2 < 'a' || c2 > 'd' && c2 != 'f')) {
       printf ("\n ERROR: Choose ONLY A-D, or F! \n Enter 4 letter grades to find statistics: ");
       scanf("%c %c %c %c", &c1, &c2, &c3, &c4); }
 while ((c3 < 'A' || c3 > 'D' && c3 != 'F') && (c3 < 'a' || c3 > 'd' && c3 != 'f')) {
       printf ("\n ERROR: Choose ONLY A-D, or F! \n Enter 4 letter grades to find statistics: ");
       scanf("%c %c %c %c", &c1, &c2, &c3, &c4); }
 while ((c4 < 'A' || c4 > 'D' && c4 != 'F') && (c4 < 'a' || c4 > 'd' && c4 != 'f')) {
       printf ("\n ERROR: Choose ONLY A-D, or F! \n Enter 4 letter grades to find statistics: ");
       scanf("%c %c %c %c", &c1, &c2, &c3, &c4); }
```

From what I understand the while loop will run if c1 is before A or after D and if its not F. But when I do this, only the lowercase input works. If I try to do uppercase it will show an input error.

I guess I don't understand how the operators work or how to implement them to make my own range for characters.

I have tried searching for my answer but I couldn't find any thing like my question.

I appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​ahhh my eyes​​​

Comment: As a style tip that doesn't answer your question: try representing ASCII characters as literal characters for clarity. i.e. replace `97` with `'a'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I would recommend using a simpler method such as mentioned in EvilTeach's answer, what seems to be the problem with your code is a precedence mistake.

I believe you're expecting `a || b && c` to be the same as `(a || b) && c`, but the compiler sees it as `a || (b && c)`. To fix your current code, put an extra set of parens around every instance of `c1 < 'A' || c1 > 'D'`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a cheap way to determine if it is bad or good.
One might suppose since you have 4 characters to check,
that maybe this code should be hidden in some sort of function.

```
if (strchr("ABCDFabcdf", c) != NULL) 
printf ("0k\n") 
else printf("bad\n");
```